# There is no statement named UserEntity.insertUser in this SqlMap

Tags: mybatis

I am trying to start with mybatis.  I did all the configurations but when i want to test the connection to the database i have that error There is no statement named UserEntity.insertUser in this SqlMap.

confif file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE configuration  
                PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"  
                "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">

        <configuration>  
                <settings>  
                    <!-- changes from the defaults -->  
                    <setting name="lazyLoadingEnabled" value="false" />  
                </settings>  
                <typeAliases>  
                    <typeAlias alias="User" type="com.hosto.Entity"/>  
                </typeAliases>  
                <environments default="development">  
                    <environment id="development">  
                        <transactionManager type="JDBC"/>  
                        <dataSource type="POOLED">  
                            <property name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>  
                            <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hospidigest"/>  
                            <property name="username" value="root"/>  
                            <property name="password" value=""/>  
                        </dataSource>  
                    </environment>  
                </environments>  
                <mappers>  
                    <mapper resource="com/hosto/mapper/UserMapper.xml"/>  
                </mappers>  
            </configuration>
```

sql mapper

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sqlMap  
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"  
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">

<sqlMap namespace="com.hosto.dao.UserDao">

<resultMap id="UserResult" class="User">

<result property="lastName" column="LASTNAME"/>
<result property="firstName" column="FIRSTNAME"/>
<result property="password" column="PASSWORD"/>
<result property="email" column="EMAIL"/>
<result property="month" column="MONTH"/>
<result property="day" column="DAY"/>   

<result property="year" column="YEAR"/>
<result property="prefixes" column="PREFIXE"/>
<result property="gender" column="GENDER"/>
<result property="personal" column="BASICPERSONNALINFORMATION"/>

</resultMap>
         <select id="getAllUsers" resultClass="java.util.ArrayList">
             SELECT * FROM user
         </select>
         <insert id="insertUser"  parameterType="com.hosto.Entity.User">
             INSERT INTO user (LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD,EMAIL,MONTH,DAY,YEAR,PREFIXE,GENDER,BASICPERSONNALINFORMATION)
             VALUES (#{lastName},#{firstName},#{userName}, #{password}, #{email}, #{month}, #{day}, #{year}, #{prefixes}, #{gender},#{personal})
         </insert>
         <update id="updateUser" parameterClass="UserDaotest">
             UPDATE user SET
                 LASTNAME= #{lastName},
                 FIRSTNAME= #{firstName},
                 USERNAME= #{userName},
                 PASSWORD= #{password},
                 EMAIL= #{email},
                 MONTH= #{month},
                 DAY= #{day},
                 YEAR= #{year},
                 PREFIXE= #{prefixes},
                 GENDER= #{gender},
                 BASICPERSONNALINFORMATION= #{personal},
             WHERE ID = #{id}
        </update>
        <delete id="deleteUser"  parameterClass="int">
            DELETE  FROM user where 
              ID = #{id}
        </delete>
        <select id="getUserById" resultClass="UserInterface" parameterClass="int">  
            SELECT *  
                FROM user  
            WHERE ID= #{id}  
       </select> 
</sqlMap>
```

Mybatis Factory

```
package com.hosto.daoconfig;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.Reader;

import org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;

import com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapClient;
import com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapClientBuilder;


public class MyBatisConnectionFactory {

    private static SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory; 

    private static SqlMapClient sqlMapClient = null;

    public static SqlMapClient getSqlMapClient()  {
            try {
            String resource = "SqlMapConfig.xml";
            Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(resource);
            sqlMapClient = SqlMapClientBuilder.buildSqlMapClient(reader);
            reader.close();

            }
            catch (IOException iOException) {
            iOException.printStackTrace();
            }
            return sqlMapClient;
     }

}
```

User Dao

```
package com.hosto.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;


import com.hosto.Entity.User;

/**
 * @author Dorian
 *
 */
public interface UserDao {

     public void insertUser(User user) throws DataAccessException;

     public User getUserById(Integer id) throws DataAccessException;

     public List<User> getAllUsers()throws DataAccessException;

     public void updateUser(User user)throws DataAccessException;

     public void deleteUser(Integer userId)throws DataAccessException;
}
```

Comment: You need to show your xml and your class for any meaningful help.

Comment: Please I need to fix it as soon as possible. Almost 4 days i feel discouraged

Answer (score 0):

It is telling you that it is not defined, you need to create one.

see this for an [example here](http://www.javawebdevelop.com/3174206/) and [here](https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/blob/master/modules/activiti-engine/src/main/resources/org/activiti/db/mapping/entity/User.xml)

Comment: Since you are starting out with MyBatis, take a look at MyBatis Generator to create the code for you: https://mybatis.github.io/generator/